# How to migrate to a newer hard disk?

Tags: 14.04, filesystem

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and as I am very new to Linux I don't know how to copy my entire setup to a new disk.

I have prepared a 500gb Hard disk drive with 5 partitions. I'd like to move my current setup to any of those.

Can this be done like copying the installed files from `/home` to my new partitions?

Answer (score 1):

**No, this is not an easy task,** nor is it *very* complicated either

*(Just a little bit complicated)*

1. **Make a [system back-up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) before you begin!** (You've just been promoted to User type 4!)
2. Insert both hard-disks into the same computer. (if you have a laptop, with space for only one hard disk, buy an external USB enclosure.)
3. [Clone](http://clonezilla.org/) the old HDD onto the new HDD.  **Warning!** if you do it the wrong way around, you will destroy all your data!  (Did I mention **[Backups](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc)**?)
4. Remove the old drive
5. Reboot uning the Ubuntu LiveCD / [GParted Live CD](http://gparted.org/),
6. Start `gparted` and *only now start* repartitioning!

Comment: And as you're a reputation 1 user: If this all works, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)